# Unable to submit survey in surveyforce

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites, survey

I am creating a new survey in my sandbox environment and i wanto get feedback from customers.So i send a sample link like with caseid and contactid links with fore.com site active page.

But when i try to submit a survey.I'm getting error like

> Error: Some error occured while saving response

And even i enabled image in header section.But when user open the link in form of email image is not displayed.

and how to debug these scenarios.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i am forgot to close this question.I gone through many posts related to this topic in other developer boards.

To enable header section to visible for other salesforce users means **Site Guest User** we need to provide field access.

Go to develop > **sites** then go to the site you created. **Click "Public Access Settings"** 
Then go to the **"Field-Level Security"** section and look for the survey object. Next to you'll see "view" click there and then you'll have to give reading permissions to the header.

And when i try to submit a survey with case & contact Id's.I'm getting error like **Some error occured while saving response**.Because site user can't able to see all contacts and cases.

So I created a public group for the survey site user and added 2 sharing rules to give case and contact read-only access.